# How can I do a query foreach tag and sort the results by the array that includes the most words?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I need to go through array and by each of the tags do a query to a db and sort the results by the result that includes the most tags.

```
public function search_db(){
    $tags=array("I","need","results","promptly");
    $results=[];

    foreach($tags as $tag){         
        $result = DB::table('foo')
            ->where('desc','like','%'.$tag.'%')
            ->orWhere('name','like','%'.$tag.'%')
            ->orWhere('url','like','%'.$tag.'%')
            ->latest()->get();

        if(count($result)>0) {
            array_push($results,$result);
        }
    }

    $results = collect($results);
    $results = $results->flatten();
    $results = $results->unique();
    $results->values()->all();
}
```

Comment: did you try with aggregated count?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You just did it worse :-) However - You should also rephrase your question. It's  not clear what you want. What do you mean by "result that includes the most tags"?

Comment: I have these blogs which has titles and body and if someone types for example something like "the dog with 5 legs" I want to search the db for a title and a body close to that query and sort the results by those that includes the most words in the query. ie result 1 includes dog and legs result 2 includes legs etc

Comment: I don't know why but this sounds like this could take some bayes algorithm and some implementation of machine learning

Comment: Do you have any idea how i solve it in the most efficient way?

Comment: you could sort them by the most result per tag. What i mean is, if tag `I` has 4 results and tag `need` has 7 results, `need` will be first and `I` will be second

Comment: Also, you could get all the results in the backend and then filter in the front end using [this technique](https://burakkanber.com/blog/machine-learning-full-text-search-in-javascript-relevance-scoring/). Its a little bit complicated as is machine learning in js but is what you are looking for

Comment: no but i think you are cofusing how the results are sorted. I need results promptly is a full query. I just explode() the query so i can look the db for each tag. SO lets say the first result is array["promptly not in here"] and second result is array["promptly results are here"] then this second result is higher in value because it has 2 tags "promptly" and "results" the first array only has "promptly"

Comment: @dianesis i may have found what you need. Please take a look at [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout)